# In Matrix notation what does it mean X 'X

Tags: notation

In matrix notation what does it mean X 'X 
I see it in this academic paper, I can't find it in matrix operation and can't search with google.

http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2400219

page 7 , paragraph 3.1

Comment: I'd guess that $X'$ means transpose, and $X'X$ is the product of two matrices.

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame. It's not like LaTeX can't just as easily produce $X^T$ or anything.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$X'$ is the transpose matrix and $X'X$ is the product the same matrix.
exemple 
$$X=\left(\matrix{1 & 2&4\\1&3&5}\right),$$ then,
$$X'X=\left(\matrix{1 & 1\\2&3\\4&5}\right)\left(\matrix{1 & 2&4\\1&3&5}\right).$$